# can't access facebook using fandjango

Tags: django, facebook, fandjango

I have fandjango setup on my django app and I have the "Site URL" pointing to the exact spot where the dynamic page is shown.

> http://www.example.com/apps/myapp

This gives me the following error message box.

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

I'm not sure how to debug this.  Looking at similar people's posts, they said they had this problem only if there was a mismatch between the site url, but even if I copy and paste the site url into my browser, I still get the same error.  I don't have https setup, if that matters.

Comment: I don't know the fandjango but I am familiar with this facebook message. Make sure fandjango knows your FACEBOOK_AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URL or other depends from propose if that not help: Would be nice if you add your fandjango settings + facebook app config. I got this error many times and always with mismatch in settings specially redirect url.

Comment: The fangjango docs say the decorator w/o parameters should return to the same URL after auth. Maybe my server isn't building that properly like using an IP instead of domain.

Comment: You should add your facebook config to question. Make sure "Site URL" and "Canvas URL" are there and APP namespace is the same as FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_NAMESPACE in settings. Check this https://github.com/jgorset/fandjango-example up also.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? can you share with us please, I have the same issue,thanks